# Need to trigger a program when Active Directory replicates

Tags: active-directory, automation

I am a .NET developer working on a project I inherited.
I need to execute a small program when AD replicates to keep our DB with user information up to date.

Is there a way when AD replicates to include the program as part of a trigger or script?

Comment: Do you really need to trigger based on a replication event?  It sure seems you need to know more then just when a replication has happened, don't you also want to know what has changed?

Comment: See this.  Perhaps you will find something useful here.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772726(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Active Directory replicates periodically on its own. You can check event logs periodically for that event ID and know within a minute or two.

With that said, AD is already a "DB with user information." You'd be much better-served by populating your user database directly from AD, or bypassing it altogether.

Comment: Agree that you should just populate your user DB with data from Active Directory. There are multiple ways of querying Active Directory and/or exporting the data from it. You can use PowerShell, VBScript, CSVDE (CSV Directory Export) or numerous other command line tools, or even a connection from SQL Server.

Comment: Yes, I already have the program written to query and extract the information from AD. I just need to have that program run when the replication takes place.  Is there a way of triggering a program to run when AD replicates ?

Comment: To my knowledge, you can't "trigger" per se, but you can certainly check logs every n minutes (where n > 1), look for the specific event ID, and fire off the script if there's a new entry with the required event ID.